# text-decoration solid not supported in IE 10

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

this code works Choreme and Firefox . But not working on İE 10 . Last td in table cannot take affect. It must turn normal.

```
     .gridview tr
     {

     font-size: 20px;
     border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; 

     padding-bottom: 3px;
     padding-top: 3px;
     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     background-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 .noadres td {
         text-decoration:line-through;
         font-style:italic;
         background-color:#f5eded;

 }
     .noadres td.etkabone {
         text-decoration:solid;
         font-style:normal;
     }
```

html

```
     <table  class="gridview">

 <tr class="noadres">
     <td>HELLO</td>
     <td>MY</td>
     <td class="etkabone" >NAME</td>

 </tr>

 </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwc7kjmo/

Comment: what is that - `text-decoration:solid;`? It seems invalid. Maybe older IE cannot fall back to legit values gracefully unlike Chrome and Firefox do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS2 the [text-decoration property](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) was a regular property with the syntax:

> none | [ underline || overline || line-through || blink ] | inherit

In the [CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration) : the `text-decoration` property is now a **shorthand property** with syntax:

> <'text-decoration-line'> || <'text-decoration-style'> ||
>   <'text-decoration-color'>

where the values for <'text-decoration-style'> are:

> **solid** | double | dotted | dashed | wavy

So now you can see why text-decoration:solid; works in Chrome and Firefox, because according to the newer spec - it is perfectly legal code.

Here is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration) for the new `text-decoration` properties.

Notice that IE doesn't support the new syntax.

So, like others have mentioned, you should use `text-decoration:none` for greater browser support.

Comment: What the hell. I was on a cave this years? I didn't know about `text-decoration-[style|color|line]`. A good insight for me. My upvote for you

Answer (score 3):

Change CSS to:

```
 .noadres td.etkabone {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:normal;
 }
```

`solid` is not valid for IE.

p.s. If you select inspect element you will see solid has a red underline.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
.noadres td.etkabone {
   text-decoration:solid; /*This is invalid value for this property for IE*/
    font-style:normal;
}
```

`solid` is the by default value of this property but IE does not support it.

You might want the normal font having no strike-through. Please change the above to the following:

```
.noadres td.etkabone {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:normal;
 }
```